# Plotting a stock chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm just getting started with Python/Pandas and put together the following code to plot the S&P 500.

```
from pandas.io.data import DataReader
# returns a DataFrame
sp500 = DataReader("^GSPC", "yahoo", start=datetime.datetime(1990, 1, 1))
sp500.plot(figsize = (12,8))
```

It looks like this is plotting the high, low, open, close, adj close, and volume all on one graph.  Is there an easy way to plot just the adj close in one graph and the volume right below it [like they do on Yahoo](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/bc?s=%5EGSPC&t=5y&l=on&z=l&q=l&c=) and most other financial sites?  I'd also be interested in an example of plotting an OHLC candlestick chart.

Comment: DataReader is no more in pandas. You have to install pandas_datareader package to continue to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250194/adding-a-subplot-to-a-matplotlib-graph/) for my answer to a similar question and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089307/financial-charts-graphs-in-ruby-or-python) for further information regarding mathplotlib's finance candlestick graph.

To get just the adj close from your  sp500, you would use something like `sp500["Adj Close"]` and then pass that to the relevant matplotlib plot command `plt.plot(datelist, sp500["Adj Close"] )` where datelist is your list of dates on the x axis.

I believe you can get datelist by referencing `sp500.index`, see [here](http://pandas.sourceforge.net/basics.html) for more information.

As for your issue with passing it to the plot command, something like

`datelist = [date2num(x) for x in sp500.index]` where the function date2num is from matplotlib.dates package.

After setting up the relevant subplot, and then call the appropriate fill command to `fill_between_alpha` the area under the line like the Yahoo graph you linked to.

See [here](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/recipes.html) under  the **Fill Between and Alpha** heading for another snippet that shows a filled line graph, with correct date printing.

The initial link has a sample matplotlib snippet which also covers the date format and formatting in more detail.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the info :-)  Do you know how I get datelist from the sp500 dataframe?  I haven't been able to figure that out yet.

Comment: I saw that you suggested I could reference sp500.index to get the datelist.  I tried plt.plot(sp500.index, sp500["adj clos"]) but got the error: ERROR: An unexpected error occurred while tokenizing input
The following traceback may be corrupted or invalid
The error message is: ('EOF in multi-line statement', (63, 0))

Comment: Actually, it looks like the thing it's choking on is sp500["adj clos"]

Comment: Ok, figured it out.  The capialization was off.  sp500["Adj Close"] works

Answer (score 0):

This gets you a plot of just the Adj Close column vs the Index of you DataFrame (Date).

```
from pandas.io.data import DataReader
sp500 = DataReader("^GSPC", "yahoo", start=datetime.datetime(1990, 1, 1)) 
close = sp500['Adj Close']
close.plot()
plt.show()
```

Likewise, You can plot the Volume the same way:

```
vol = sp500['Volume']
vol.plot()
plt.show()
```